# ansible generate file loop dictionary

Tags: ansible, jinja2

```
---
- name: main
  hosts: all
  become: true
  vars:
    sudoers_include:
      sudofile1:
          - "%kombit ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/create_sftp_dirs.sh"
          - "%kombit ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/add_public_key.sh"
          - "%kombit ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/remove_sftp_dirs.sh"
          - "%kombit ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/lock_file.sh"
          - "%kombit ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/unlock_file.sh"
      sudofile2:
          - "%admin1 ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/create_sftp_dirs.sh"
          - "%admin2 ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/add_public_key.sh"
  tasks:
  - copy:
     dest: "/tmp/{{item.key}}"
     content: |
          {%- for k,v in sudoers_include.items() -%}
              {% for c in v -%}
                {{c}}
              {% endfor -%}
          {%- endfor -%}
    loop: "{{ sudoers_include | dict2items }}"
```

However, this generate something like::

Either I\m using the wrong approach or I do miss something in defining the loop ?

```
 root@localhost:~# cat /tmp/sudofile1
 %kombit ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/create_sftp_dirs.sh
 %kombit ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/add_public_key.sh
 %kombit ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/remove_sftp_dirs.sh
 %kombit ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/lock_file.sh
 %kombit ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/unlock_file.sh
 %admin1 ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/create_sftp_dirs.sh
 %admin2 ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/add_public_key.sh
```

So, the idea is to generate the sudoers file...
Don't know if the best approach would be templates or  or the copy module ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: ***"Would the best approach be templates or the copy module?"***

A: The only difference is the template in a file vs. in a [block](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#chapter-8-block-style-productions).

---

Q: ***"Do I miss something in defining the loop?"***

A: The fixed template in the below *content*

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: "/tmp/{{ item.key }}"
        content: |
          {% for c in item.value %}
          {{ c }}
          {% endfor %}
      loop: "{{ sudoers_include|dict2items }}"
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/sudofile1 
%kombit ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/create_sftp_dirs.sh
%kombit ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/add_public_key.sh
%kombit ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/remove_sftp_dirs.sh
%kombit ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/lock_file.sh
%kombit ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/unlock_file.sh
```

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/sudofile2
%admin1 ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/create_sftp_dirs.sh
%admin2 ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/add_public_key.sh
```

Comment: Thanks ,  
I've got it, fell like i'm less noob now in template for ansible :)